# highlighting the last of each half-hour bar on a minute chart

Tags: pine-script

The users manual gives the code for highlighting the beginning of each half-hour bar on a minute chart in the following way:

```
//@version=4
study("new 30 min bar")
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
plot(is_newbar("30") ? 1 : 0)
```

How do i find the 1 min bar representing the LAST bar in each half-hour?
I wish to place an order on that bar close.

Alternatively, can i place an order on the bar OPEN when using "is newbar" and not when that bar closes?

Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out.
The code below highlights the last bar in the chart that corresponds to specified higher resolution.

```
//@version=4
study("is_lastbar_htf(res)", overlay=true)

//=== INPUT RESOLUTION OF HIGHER TIME FRAME ===
resInt = input(title="Higher time frame. Min 3min Max 1440min", type=input.integer, defval=30, minval=3, maxval=1440) // Sets the resolution of the higher time frame
res = tostring(resInt) // Converts the resolution of the higher time frame into a string


//=== ISOLATES THE BAR ON THE CURRENT CHART THAT IS THE LAST BAR OF THE HIGHER TIME FRAME ===
is_lastbar_htf(res) => 
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[(resInt/timeframe.multiplier)-1])
bgcolor(not is_lastbar_htf(res) ? color.red : na)
```